# Angular-hottowel gulp serve-build failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm runing Ubuntu 14.10 64Bits. Node.js version is 0.12.2 and NPM version is 2.7.4.

**This is not the Visual Studio project, rather https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel

I can't figure out this one, after running either `gulp serve-build` or just `gulp build` I get this error:

```
[14:36:52] Finished 'inject' after 236 ms
**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/index.js:99
          this.emit('error', new gutil.PluginError('gulp-jscs', out.join('\n\n'), {
                                                                      ^ RangeError: Invalid string length
    at Array.join (native)
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/index.js:99:62)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:135:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:199:16)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at finishMaybe (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:371:12)
    at endWritable (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:378:3)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.end (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jscs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:356:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (**PATH-TO-MY-PROJECT**/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:199:16)
```

I have a JSCS plugin for Sublime Text 3 and I can't find any error in the style. Could anyone give me a hand please?

** EDIT **
I've tried clearing the cache and also installing different versions of the plugin, but it either displays a different error, or presents the same issue.

So I went ahead and added a try/catch block on the `index.js` file in the plugin. This allows the execution of the rest of the gulp tasks in my `gulp.js` file but I wouldn't consider it as a solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The JSCS gulp plugin has nothing to do with the sublime plguin. It seems your plugin has an error.

I can't say with this information where it comes from. Often deleting the node modules and reinstalling it by doing:

```
npm cache clear
npm i
```

helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, I know it has nothing to do with it, I was just pointing out that I can't quite see the error by hand. I have removed the whole node_modules folder and ran ```npm install``` again. Would clearing chache make a difference?

Comment: Sometimes it helps. That depends in the error. Its just the easiest thing to try.